# Entity Framework Core v3 : Eliminating repeating data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core v3. I am currently trying to retrieve data from tables that contain a one-to-many relationship.

The tables here are `PersonNote` and `PersonNoteAttachment`.

One `PersonNote` can have many `PersonNoteAttachments`. Data is getting currently repeated. So if you see the result section it has Name appearing twice. This is just an example. I am not sure if I need to change the query or change the model structure etc. Could somebody help

PersonNote

```
Id   Name
-------------
113  TestNote
```

PersonNoteAttachment

```
Id  PersonNoteId   Note 
---------------------------------
101 113            Attachment1
102 113            Attachment2
```

Result

```
TestNote Attachment1
TestNote Attachment2
```

What I am looking at is

```
TestNote Attachment1
          Attachment2
```

Query

```
public IQueryable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
{
    var personNotes = _context.PersonNotes
             .Include(x => x.Person)
             .Include(x => x.Author)
             .Include(x => x.PersonNoteAttachment)
             .Where(p => p.PersonId == personId)
             .OrderByDescending(d => d.Created);

    return personNotes;
}
```

Model

```
namespace Organisation.Models.DataModels
{
    [Table(nameof(PersonNote), Schema = "common")]
    public class PersonNote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public PersonNoteAttachment PersonNoteAttachment { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
        public Person Author { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordStartDateTime { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordEndDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class PersonNoteAttachment
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int PersonNoteId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PersonNoteId")]
        public PersonNote PersonNote { get; set; }

        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
        public int Deleted { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordStartDateTime { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordEndDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```
 CreateMap<Organisation.Models.DataModels.PersonNote, Organisation.Models.User.PersonNote>()
                  .ForMember(t => t.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
                  .ForMember(t => t.PersonId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonId))
                  .ForMember(t => t.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Author.FirstName + " " + s.Author.LastName))
                  .ForMember(t => t.FileName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.FileName))
                  .ForMember(t => t.MimeType, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.MimeType))
                  .ForMember(t => t.Alias, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.Alias))
                  .ForMember(t => t.Note, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Note))
                  .ForMember(t => t.AuthorId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.AuthorId))
                  .ForMember(t => t.CreatedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.CreatedBy))
                  .ForMember(t => t.Created, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Created));
```

If you notice `PersonNoteAttachment` is not an array. If I make it an array, then the following changes would need to be done:

```
 public PersonNoteAttachment[] PersonNoteAttachment { get; set; }
```

and in the mapping to avoid compile errors

```
.ForMember(t => t.FileName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment[0].FileName))
```

API

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetPersonNote))]
[UsedImplicitly]
public Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "person-note/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
            int id) => _helper.HandleAsync(async () =>
{
    // await _helper.ValidateRequestAsync(req,  SecurityPolicies.ViewNotes);
    var personNotes = await _organisationRepository.GetPersonNotes(id).ProjectTo<PersonNote>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
    return new OkObjectResult(personNotes);
});
```

ViewModel

```
namespace Organisation.Models.User
{
    [Table(nameof(PersonNote), Schema = "common")]
    public class PersonNote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Solution 1 - But with internal exception**

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Int32'.
```

Tried the following , which is  providing the desired results . The postman returns 200k. Although debugging the code throwing an internal exception.

Added

Datamodel

```
  namespace Organisation.Models.DataModels
    {
    public class PersonNote
        {
          public IEnumerable<PersonNoteAttachment> PersonNoteAttachment { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Viewmodel

```
namespace Organisation.Models.User
{
    [Table(nameof(PersonNote), Schema = "common")]
    public class PersonNote
    {

        public IEnumerable<string> Alias { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> FileName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> MimeType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Mapping

```
.ForMember(t => t.FileName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.Select(x=> x.FileName)))
                  .ForMember(t => t.MimeType, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.Select(x => x.MimeType)))
                  .ForMember(t => t.Alias, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonNoteAttachment.Select(x => x.Alias)))
```

**Abduls solution**

```
    API



  [FunctionName(nameof(GetPersonNote))]
        [UsedImplicitly]
        public Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "person-note/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
            int id) => _helper.HandleAsync(async () =>
        {
            await _helper.ValidateRequestAsync(req,  SecurityPolicies.ViewNotes);
            var personNotes =  _organisationRepository.GetPersonNotes(id);
            //IEnumerable<PersonNote> personNotes =  groupedNotes.Select(Profiles.GenistarUserProfile.MapGroupToPersonNote);

            return new OkObjectResult(personNotes.ToList());
        });
```

Repository

```
public IQueryable<Genistar.Organisation.Models.User.PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
    {
        var personNotes = _context.PersonNotes
            .Include(x => x.Person)
            .Include(x => x.Author)
            .Where(p => p.PersonId == personId).Select(x => new Genistar.Organisation.Models.User.PersonNote
            {
                //assign all properties
                Attachments = _context.PersonNotesAttachments.Where(y => y.PersonNoteId == x.Id).Select(y => new Genistar.Organisation.Models.User.PersonNoteAttachment
                {
                    FileName = y.FileName,
                    Alias = y.Alias,
                    MimeType = y.MimeType

                }),
                PersonId = x.PersonId,
                AuthorName = x.Person.FirstName + " " + x.Person.LastName,
                Note = x.Note,
                Id = x.Id,
                Created = x.Created
            }).OrderByDescending(x=> x.Created).AsNoTracking();
        return personNotes; 
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205715/discussion-on-question-by-tom-entity-framework-core-v3-eliminating-repeating-d).

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to use a 3 layered architecture with your app, and try to reduce the coupling between your layers while keeping your existing structure.

To start, change your query:

```
public IQueryable<DataModel.PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
{
    var personNotes = _context.PersonNotes
         .Include(x => x.Person)
         .Include(x => x.Author)
         .Where(p => p.PersonId == personId);

    return personNotes;
}
```

And add another repo query:

```
public IQueryable<DataModel.PersonNoteAttachment> GetAttachments(int personNoteId)
{
    var attachments = _context.PersonNotesAttachments.Where(x => x.Id == personNoteId);

    return attachments ;
}
```

Use the following Models, `PersonNote` being your ViewModel:

```
namespace Organisation.Models.User
{
    public class PersonNoteAttachment
    {
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonNote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PersonNoteAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now we create a new function in BL layer that will return your data for the ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<User.PersonNote> GetPersonNotesAndAttachments(int personID)
{
    var personNotes = _organisationRepository.GetPersonNotes(id).Select(x => 
        new User.PersonNote
        {
            //assign all properties
            Attachments = _organisationRepository.GetAttachments(x.PersonNoteID).Select(y => 
            new User.PersonNoteAttachment
            {
                FileName = y.FileName,
                Alias = y.Alias,
                MimeType = y.MimeType
            }).AsEnumerable(),
        PersonId = x.PersonId,
        AuthorName = x.Person.FirstName + " " + x.Person.LastName,
        Note = x.Note,
        Id = x.Id,
        Created = x.Created
        });

    return personNotes;
}
```

The `IEnumerable<PersonNote>` "What I am looking at is" can be accessed like this:

```
IEnumerable<User.PersonNote> personNotes = new BlClass().GetPersonNotesAndAttachments(id);
```

Comment: I have updated the post with your proposed solution. Had to make slight amendments . Getting two compile time errors. Could you please let me know

Comment: Please note that i added the brackets in the attachment's assignment

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up. Can we continue in the chat to work out the kinks?

Comment: Can we touch base in half an hour .

Comment: I see a few issues in your code, `DataModels.PersonNote` should be what you originally had. Next, you should have `User.PersonNote` as a ViewModel, but also a Model `User.PersonNoteAttachments`. Then your 1st compile error can be fixed by changing `public List<PersonNoteAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }` to `public IEnumerable<PersonNoteAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }`. Your 2nd error can be resolved by including reference to `System.Linq`

Comment: can we chat please

Comment: I have added user.PersonNoteAttachment and now get error Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Organisation.Models.DataModels.PersonNoteAttachment>' 
to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Organisation.Models.User.PersonNoteAttachment>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Tom click the chat link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205715/discussion-on-question-by-tom-entity-framework-core-v3-eliminating-repeating-d

Comment: I have updated the post with Abdul's solution which works . My only concern is that we are passing the ViewModel from the repository layer instead of business layer. There is no mapping with automapper used. Could somebody advice if they know any  solution for returning the datamodel from the repository and viewmodel from business layer and handle the mapping the in mapping class

Comment: I am going to update my answer with what the code should look like

Comment: @Tom no not yet, not at a computer

Comment: You should create another question if you insist on having this solution use Automapper.

Comment: I tried your solution above. GetPersonNotes gets called but I dont see GetAttachments getting called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205788/discussion-between-tom-and-abdulg).